# Concatenating strings in C includes unwanted chars

Tags: arrays, c, char, string-concatenation

I created a program to concatenate two strings. However I get some extra characters included in the output string when the char array is too small.

Faulty code below:

```
char c[3] = "abc";
char d[3] = "def";
char result[8];

strcpy(result, c);
strcat(result, d);

printf("%s\n, result);
```

Prints `abc{def�`

Running the program without recompiling gives random chars each time. E.g `abc�tdef�` .

Changing the size of the result variable makes no difference:

```
char c[3] = "abc";
char d[3] = "def";
char result[6];
```

gives`abcrdef�`

I know that I need to change the size of the char arrays to 'c[4]' to produce expected output. This is to have space for null termination?

Furthermore, why are those symbols added?
What decides why **exactly** those chars were included when they appear to be randomly selected?

Why does the result array acceept more chars than written? E.g 'char result[1]' gives 'abcdef' as output.

I've tried googling for answers.

Comment: "*This is to have space for null termination?*" -- yes.

Comment: "*What decides why **exactly** those chars were included when they appear to be randomly selected?*" At the C-language level, nothing.  Your `strcpy()` and `strcat()` calls are overrunning the bounds of your arrays, and the resulting behavior is undefined.

Comment: `char c[3] = "abc";` defines and initializes the array `c`, but `c` is not a string (since it does not have a terminator).  `strcpy` requires that its 2nd argument be a string.  Passing a non-string as the 2nd argument of strcpy is UB.

Comment: To fulfill `strcpy` requirements the array of chars can then be written as `char c[4]="abc\0"` or `char c[4]="abc"`?

Comment: I'm still learning C, not trying to invoke undefined behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

`char[3]` is not big enough to hold "abc", it needs to be `char[4]`. instead do

```
 char c[] = "abc";
```

and let the compiler work out the size for you, same for "def"

the resulting size will be 7 (not 6 or 8)

Comment: Yes I know that it needs to be at least 'char[4]' (even wrote so in the post). I'm more interested in the why's for this specific case.

Comment: becuase `char[3]=abc` produces a c string that has no null at the end (theres no space for it) so strcat doesnt know where the end is, it keeps going to till it finds a \0. likewise strcat doesnt know where the end of "def" is because it has no \0 at the end either

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy(result, c);
```

The above call to `strcpy()` invokes undefined behaviour¹ because the second argument is not a null-terminated string.

The subsequent calls to `strcat()` and `printf()` trigger undefined behaviour in a similar way.

> I know that I need to change the size of the char arrays to 'c[4]' to
> produce expected output. This is to have space for null termination?

Indeed.

> What decides why exactly those chars were included when they appear to
> be randomly selected?

*At the C-language level, nothing. Your strcpy() and strcat() calls are overrunning the bounds of your arrays, and the resulting behavior is undefined.* — John Bollinger

> Why does the result array acceept more chars than written? E.g 'char
> result[1]' gives 'abcdef' as output.

Once a program reaches a state of undefined behaviour, no further assumption about the continuation of the execution of the program can be made.

> To fulfill strcpy requirements the array of chars can then be written
> as char c[4]="abc\0" or char c[4]="abc"?

An explicit null-byte is not required. Simply:

```
char c[4] = "abc";
```

Or even better, let the compiler determine the length:

```
char c[] = "abc";
```

---

### Footnote:

1 — From the C11 standard:

> Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation
> completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation
> or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
> environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to
> terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
> diagnostic message).